# UIImage animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Maybe is there a way to do animation only on one image?
So if I have an UIImage and I want to animate it like a wave. Is this possible? And if yes, can you give me some examples or a link to start or something like this? (I used google but didn't find any good start link...)

Comment: By wave, do you mean that the whole image moves up and down like a boat on a wave, or do you mean that the image itself distorts in a wave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL ES is another possibility.  Apple provide all the code to set up a rendering context.

From there you just need to get your image into a texture, define some vertices (more than just four), and move each vertex on a sine wave.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you may want to look into cocos2d - http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org

or OpenGL ES as mentioned above

or Quartz

It all depends on what this 'Wave' effect needs to look like, if it's what i think, you couldn't achieve that by using Core Animation, you would need to look in to these suggestions.

Comment: and without cocos2d? this is a big framework, I want to animate only one image...